# Xamarin XMPP client library

Tags: android, xamarin, xmpp, cross-platform, chat

I have spent the whole day looking for a XMPP client library that will work in Xamarin.
Specifically put , I am developing a cross platform app with a portable class library (Xamarin Forms). I have gone through `Sharp.Xmpp, s22.xmp, agsSharp and UbietyXMPP`.

Each one have its own peculiar plugging in issue with Xamarin.
Is there any tested and tried client library that is compatible with Xamarin?

The following is the error text of each client libraries while adding from `NuGet` and in the case of `agsXmpp` the compile time error log.

Error messages for client libraries:

> AgsXmpp
>
> Error 2   Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly
>   'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono
>   for Android profile? File name: 'System.Drawing.dll'    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() whattf.Droid
>
> S22.Xmpp
>
> Installing 'S22.Xmpp 1.0.0.0'. Successfully installed 'S22.Xmpp
>   1.0.0.0'. Adding 'S22.Xmpp 1.0.0.0' to whattf.Droid. Uninstalling 'S22.Xmpp 1.0.0.0'. Successfully uninstalled 'S22.Xmpp 1.0.0.0'.
>   Install failed. Rolling back... Could not install package 'S22.Xmpp
>   1.0.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>
> XMPP
>
> Installing 'XMPP 0.7.0.21'. Successfully installed 'XMPP 0.7.0.21'.
>   Adding 'XMPP 0.7.0.21' to whattf.Droid. Uninstalling 'XMPP 0.7.0.21'.
>   Successfully uninstalled 'XMPP 0.7.0.21'. Install failed. Rolling
>   back... Could not install package 'XMPP 0.7.0.21'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>
> UbietyXMPP
>
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'SharpZipLib (= 0.86.0)'. Attempting
>   to resolve dependency 'Heijden.Dns (= 1.0.0)'. Attempting to resolve
>   dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl (= 1.1.10)'. Attempting to resolve
>   dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (= 1.0.14)'. Attempting to resolve
>   dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (= 1.0.21)'. Attempting to resolve
>   dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (= 2.2.29)'. Attempting to resolve
>   dependency 'Serilog (= 1.5.9)'. Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'Serilog.Sinks.Seq (= 1.5.15)'. Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'libidn (= 1.29.1)'. Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'ExceptionAnalyzer (= 1.0.5)'. Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'Microsoft.AnalyzerPowerPack (= 1.0.1)'. Installing 'SharpZipLib
>   0.86.0'. Successfully installed 'SharpZipLib 0.86.0'. Installing 'Heijden.Dns 1.0.0'. Successfully installed 'Heijden.Dns 1.0.0'.
>   Installing 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10'. Successfully installed
>   'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10'. Installing 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21'.
>   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21'. Installing
>   'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29'. Successfully installed
>   'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29'. Installing 'Serilog 1.5.9'. Successfully
>   installed 'Serilog 1.5.9'. Installing 'Serilog.Sinks.Seq 1.5.15'.
>   Successfully installed 'Serilog.Sinks.Seq 1.5.15'. Installing 'libidn
>   1.29.1'. Successfully installed 'libidn 1.29.1'. Installing 'ExceptionAnalyzer 1.0.5'. Successfully installed 'ExceptionAnalyzer
>   1.0.5'. Installing 'Microsoft.AnalyzerPowerPack 1.0.1'. Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AnalyzerPowerPack 1.0.1'. Installing 'UbietyXMPP
>   0.7.37.0'. Successfully installed 'UbietyXMPP 0.7.37.0'. Adding 'SharpZipLib 0.86.0' to whattf.Droid. Uninstalling 'SharpZipLib
>   0.86.0'. Successfully uninstalled 'SharpZipLib 0.86.0'. Install failed. Rolling back... Could not install package 'SharpZipLib
>   0.86.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin is a subset of the full .NET framework and uses its own core libraries. This is why you will not get those libraries running without recompiling them for Xamarin and doing some modifications to the source when required.

The MatriX XMPP library is available for Xamarin iOS and Android. But its a commercial product.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be the last option I think. Thanks .

Comment: I am doing  R&D for developing a chat application for my company. And we are interested to know trial and licensing requirements for your product

Comment: I tried out Matrix library and it had thrown this error                                Error 2 The base class or interface 'System.ComponentModel.Component' in assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type 'Matrix.XmppStream' could not be resolved  .

Comment: you are using a wrong build I guess. Make sure you use the correct Xamarin packages

Comment: I am  using Xamarin  Forms with PCL

Comment: I created a new Xamarin project with forms and  shared library . The error I previously mentioned is gone but now another error comes up..  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Comment: File name: 'System.Windows.Forms.dll'   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() (bubbles.Droid) . I scanned Matrix.dll at scan.xamarin.com and this is their scan report : [link](http://scan.xamarin.com/Home/Report?scanId=75f4c76d-0977-4f2b-a1a2-275a2203d55d ). The report says library references the windows.forms dll.

Comment: By the way , I need to add the Matrix.dll directly in the assembly reference after downloading the Nuget package. I am able to  call the Matrix package in my code only after adding the dll directly. is this specific to Xamarin platform?

Comment: Matrix references system.drawing and windows.forms. That's causing the error.  Windows.forms ,I think used to show the evaluation version  selection screen and system.drawing is used to implement VCards( My best guess). Matrix worked like a charm in a windows console  app anyway

Comment: no it doesn't for Xamarin, you are still using a MatriX.dll for the wrong platform

Comment: yes.you're right...i used MatriX XMPP SDK build . I should have gone for MatriX for Android (Mono for Android) build

Comment: MatriX is a the only library i managed to get working. But the license os too expensive.

Comment: @jzeferino, does that mean there is no open source option for xmpp on xamarin?

Comment: @Najeeb Im not updated on the topic, but probably there are some new options out there.